# Parse curl_exec() result PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm working with a Shipping Company web service using `curl_exec()`.

The query result is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="#Oca_Express_Pak">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Tarifador" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Precio" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="idTiposervicio" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Ambito" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlazoEntrega" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Adicional" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Total" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="XML" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <Tarifador>23</Tarifador>
        <Precio>383.4100</Precio>
        <idTiposervicio>3</idTiposervicio>
        <Ambito>Nacional 1</Ambito>
        <PlazoEntrega>9</PlazoEntrega>
        <Adicional>0.0000</Adicional>
        <Total>383.4100</Total>
        <XML>&lt;row Tarifador="23" Precio="383.4100"/&gt;</XML>
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

How I can parse the result to get the fields `PlazoEntrega` and `Total`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `preg_match()`:

```php
//$text = your curl result.
    preg_match('/<PlazoEntrega>(.*)<\/PlazoEntrega>/',$text,$matches);
    $plazo = $matches[1];
    preg_match('/<Total>(.*)<\/Total>/',$text,$matches);
    $total = $matches[1];
```

PHP has an XML parser:

```php
simplexml_load_file() and simplexml_load_string();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! 
Someone knows if I can parse as an xml in php, writing $curl->Table->Total ?